# C# WinForms Select in ComboBox_ColumnSchedule then open the ComboBox_BeamSchedule

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

Sorry Guyz but I will post here the related codes for my queries:

```
                   private void InitializeComboBox(ComboBox ComboBoxX)
    {
        ComboBoxX.Size = new Size(Spacing, Spacing);
        ComboBoxX.BackColor = this.BackColor;
        ComboBoxX.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        ComboBoxX.Visible = false;
        ComboBoxX.Font = new Font("Arial Narrow", 12);
        Controls.Add(ComboBoxX);
    }

  private void ColumnInformation()
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i <= NumberOfColumnLabel; i++)
        {
            ComboBox_ColumnType[i] = new ComboBox();

            InitializeComboBox(ComboBox_ColumnType[i]);
            ComboBox_ColumnType[i].Width = Label_Type.Width;
            ComboBox_ColumnType[i].Visible = true;

            ComboBox_ColumnType[i].Items.Add("A");
            ComboBox_ColumnType[i].Items.Add("B");
            ComboBox_ColumnType[i].Items.Add("C");
            ComboBox_ColumnType[i].Items.Add("D");
            ComboBox_ColumnType[i].Items.Add("E");
            ComboBox_ColumnType[i].Location = new Point(Label_Type.Location.X, Label_ColumnScheduleFirst[i].Location.Y);

            ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i] = new ComboBox();
            InitializeComboBox(ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i]);
            ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Width = Label_Type.Width;
            ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Visible = false;
            ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Location = new Point(Label_Mirror.Location.X, Label_ColumnScheduleFirst[i].Location.Y);
        }
        OpeningMirror();
    }


    private void OpeningMirror()
    {
        int i;
        int j;

        for (i = 1; i <= NumberOfColumnLabel; i++)
        {
               ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Items.Clear();
ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Visible = false;
            ComboBox_ColumnType[i].SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (ComboBox_ColumnType[i].SelectedItem == "D")
                    {
                        ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Visible = true;
                        for (j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
                        {
                            ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Items.Add(j);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (ComboBox_ColumnType[i].SelectedItem == "E")
                    {
                        ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Visible = true;
                        for (j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
                        {
                            ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Items.Add(j);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ComboBox_ColumnMirror[i].Visible = false;
                    }
                };
        }
    }
```

if item "D" or Item "E" selected, related combobox will open, esp. Combobox_mirror and the visibility=true, but if the user change his mind and select item "A" or "B" or "C", no combobox will appear as it they stay hidden, it's a synchronize of event.

Comment: You forgot 2 things: snippet of related code and .. the question. =D

Comment: Plase show us your code and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: also what technology? winforms, wpf, webforms, ... ?

Comment: @SonGozita still not very enlightening... ever read the article [ask]?

Comment: @SonGozita we need a little more info... you have to help us to help you

Comment: something like... If a user will select Item A in ComboBox_ColumnSchedule, another combobox will open(ComboBox_BeamSchedule). If (ComboBox_ColumnSchedule[1].Text=="A") {ComboBox_BeamSchedule.Visible=true} else{}

Comment: Hopefully you got my point. I Hope.

Comment: @SonGozita so... this is about winforms? you have 10 comboboxes with "A"-"E" as items and you want that extra combobox to be visible if the 6th has "A" selected... did i get this right?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger sorry I have some mistake, the beamschedule has also 10 combobox. then if any of this comboxes in comboboxcolumn selects "A", then the comboboxbeam will open......... ex. ComboBox_Column[2].Text="A" then ComboBox_Beam[2].Visible=true;

Comment: sorry guyz but I post here the related codes. Hopefully it will finally answered my queries. I'm just a newbie in C#.

Comment: @SonGozita can you add a screenshot or mockup? this code is pretty hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I don't know what layout you actually have but this can be the template to work from):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ComboBoxPair pair = new ComboBoxPair(i*20);
            InitializeComboBoxPair(pair);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComboBoxPair(ComboBoxPair comboBoxPair)
    {
        Controls.Add(comboBoxPair.ColumnSchedule);
        Controls.Add(comboBoxPair.BeamSchedule);
    }

}

public class ComboBoxPair
{
    public ComboBox ColumnSchedule { get; private set; }
    public ComboBox BeamSchedule { get; private set; }

    public ComboBoxPair(int top)
    {
        ColumnSchedule = new ComboBox();
        ColumnSchedule.Top = top;
        ColumnSchedule.Items.AddRange("ABCDE".Cast<object>().ToArray());
        ColumnSchedule.SelectedIndexChanged += ColumnSchedule_SelectedIndexChanged;
        BeamSchedule = new ComboBox();
        BeamSchedule.Top = top;
        BeamSchedule.Items.AddRange("ABCDE".Select(c => string.Format("{0}{0}",c)).ToArray());
        BeamSchedule.Left = ColumnSchedule.Right;
        BeamSchedule.Visible = false;
    }

    private void ColumnSchedule_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BeamSchedule.Visible = ColumnSchedule.SelectedIndex > -1;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I post here the related codes. Hopefully it will finally answered my queries. I'm just a newbie in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to react to changes on the combo box. Add an id to your generated combo box to identify it in the event handler.

You can then decide whether to show the other combo box or not, depending on the id.

```
ComboBox_ColumnSchedule[i] = new ComboBox();
ComboBox_ColumnSchedule[i].Id = "Cbx_" + id;
ComboBox_ColumnSchedule[i].SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
...

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

    //replace with your criteria
    ComboBox_BeamSchedule.Visible = comboBox.Id == "Cbx_2";
    ...
}
```

Comment: In WPF use the property **Name**